# Is Context.Cache potentially removing items mid-request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, iis

Suppose I have a snippet like the following which returns the contents of Context.Cache["someComplexObject"]:

```
public class Something {
    private static SortedDictionary<Guid, Object> ComplexObjectCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (Context.Cache["someComplexObject"] == null)
            {
                FillCache();
            }
            return (SortedDictionary<Guid, Object>)Context.Cache["someComplexObject"];
        }

        set
        {
            Int32 seconds = (new Random()).Next(120, 180);
            Context.Cache.Add(
                "someComplexObject",
                value,
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds),
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And in a user control, suppose I have this:

```
Object o = Something.ComplexObjectCache[someGuid];

/* 

    do some other stuff ...

*/

DoSomethingWith(o);
```

On very rare occasional, I've seen exceptions which would lead me to believe that **o** is no longer in memory when **DoSomethingWith(o)** is hit. I'm 97% sure there's are no other parallel processes occurring, other than whatever the cache is doing. I'm seeing other weird phenomena that would lead me to believe the cache key is either empty or incomplete.

Can/Will the cache really remove an object from memory, even if there's still a pointer to it elsewhere? If so, how do I combat that?

### UPDATE

After further digging, I found that we had a **related** cache item (an index) that's causing issues when it expires prior to the "main" cache item. I've redone the caching code for this entity to store these two structures *together* in an Object array. This seems to have solved the problem.

None of you had enough information to solve the problem. So, I'll review the answers and give the checkmark to whichever answer seems to have most accurately addressed the question *as given*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache will never remove anything from memory.

It's the garbage collector that removes object from memory, and that can happen only when there are no more references to the object. So, the objects will not be removed from memory, even if they are dropped from the cache, as long as you have a reference to it.

(The cache can drop references to objects mid request. As several threads can handle requests at the same time, something can happen in a different thread that makes the cache drop items. The cache can't wait until all threads are idle to drop items, then it might never be able to do that, and you would run out of memory.)

Comment: Can you verify that the cache isn't managing a predefined segment of memory? If it is, it would make sense for it to be following slightly different rules.

Comment: Maybe a more useful question: If what you're saying is accurate, on my development box, wherein typically only a single request is being executed at any given time, what could be causing the corruption?

Comment: @svidgen: It's not corruption. As you try to add items with the same key to the cache, only the first item will be in the cache, with its original expiration time. The other items will be ignored. The item in the cache will be removed when it has expired, and sometimes this will happen between the time that you try to add an item and the time when you try to read the item.

Comment: I don't follow. The first snippet above only adds an item to cache when the requested item isn't there. The second snippet successfully grabs an object, but the object (in very rare cases) isn't "complete."

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. If the web server is pressed for memory even code like this will fail to print "foo".

```
Context.Cache.Add(
            "someComplexObject",
            "foo",
            null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds),
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            null
        );

Response.Write(Cache["someComplexObject").ToString());
```

You need to do something smart, like

```
string val = "foo";

Context.Cache.Add(
            "someComplexObject",
            val,
            null,
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds),
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            null
        );

Response.Write(val.ToString());
```

Also, you need to lock any time you read or write to the cache. You can use a ReaderWriterLock (or similar) for this. This is to avoid reads when the cache is being written (and writes when the cache is being read).

I've implemented a couple of caches for the [SixPack library](http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library), which you may find interesting, for example see this [CacheController](http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library/source/browse/branches/dotnet2.0/src/SixPack/ComponentModel/CacheController.cs) class.

As a side note, that class is a tad more complex than you need because it's part of a system to allow you to cache like so:

```
[Cached]
public class MyTime : ContextBoundObject
{
        [CachedMethod(1)]
        public DateTime Get()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Get invoked.");
                return DateTime.Now;
        }

        public DateTime GetNoCache()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("GetNoCache invoked.");
                return DateTime.Now;
        }
}
```

[Full Example](http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library/wiki/Caching)

[NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/SixPack)

Comment: What you're saying makes some sense. But, I'll have to think it through again when I'm in the office on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Cache is free to remove objects whenever it feels so. I.e. it can detect memory pressure and drop items as soon as you add them.

You really should not be using Cache to pass objects around. Cache is cache - store objects to speed things up in future, but use other means to pass objects during single request. Also note that Cache is shared unlike something like [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx).

Comment: Right. The point here is to load a fairly static tree from the database, compile it into a quickly traversable object in memory, and then not have to spend the extra 5/100th to 1/10th of a second for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your FillCache method is populating the cache, but there is time between that and when you retrieve the contents of the cache. In this time your cache can be invalidated. Try returning from your FillCache method so you always have a solid reference:

```
private SortedDictionary<Guid, Object> ComplexObjectCache()
{
    if (Context.Cache["someComplexObject"] == null)
    {
       var cacheItems = FillCache();
       return cacheItems;
    }
    return (SortedDictionary<Guid, Object>)Context.Cache["someComplexObject"];
}
```